# can 2 configerable products use the same simple products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, products, products-management, inventory

Is it possible to do the following:

I have 2 categories, day collection and summer wraps.

I have a product 'monty scarf' which comes in 3 colours and wish to appear in both of the above categories.

BUT I want the images to be different in the product page. So day collection/monty scarf would have day shots of the scarf and summer wraps/monty scarf would have beach scene shots.

If I make 2 sets of the same configurable and simple products using different images I would ended up with a inventory problem as it essential the same stock just a different set of product images.

can I have 2 configurable products, using the different images as above but associate the same simple products so the inventory would be accurate

I am using magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Since stock is managed on simple product level and images on configurable product level, this is the right approach for you.